# How to store & read events specific to an Aggregate from Kafka in an ES/CQRS application?

Tags: apache-kafka, event-sourcing

I'm trying to understand how other developers are using Kafka for Eventsourcing. I can't find much help googling. My question is specific to rebuilding the state of an Aggregate reading the Events that only that are specific to that aggregate.

Suppose I have a UserAggregate which stores the following events and lets assume my application has a million users and there are about 10 million events stored in total.

```
UserCreated(email: String, password: String)
UserPasswordUpdated(password: String)
UserEmailUpdated(email: String)
```

Since in an eventsourced application we have to rebuild the state of an Aggregate every time a new command occurs for an Aggregate. To rebuild the state I have to re-read the Events that occurred for that Aggregate from Kafka.

- I can have 1 topic per Aggregate type. So one topic that stores
  events related to all UserAggregates. But what if a `User`'s account was created and 3 years later (probably millions of other User events later) user wants to update his/her email. If the events are this far apart how is this going to effect the query each time I want to rebuild the state of a `User` ?
- If I created a topic or a partition per `UserAggregate` the problem I read about are that creating a million topics or partitions will exhaust `Zookeeper` ?

Comment: I think it is bit too much opinion-based question, rather than technical one, so answering in comment, not a proper answer. I think that kafka is a wrong solution for your problem. It does NOT scale to millions of separate topics. It is not really designed to keep data for years as a golden source. It does not support any kind of reasonable queries. What you need is some kind of database (sql or nosql) with append-only tables and few indices. Now, for your 'small' problem, you can keep it on kafka and just load everything into memory for queries, but you will be more happy with mysql or mongo.

Comment: I'm currently using Postgres but a fellow co worker has been suggesting that I used Kafka instead hence the question. I guess I will stick with Postgres. Thank you for your advice Artur :)

Comment: https://www.confluent.io/blog/event-sourcing-cqrs-stream-processing-apache-kafka-whats-connection/